# Lightswitch application error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, visual-studio-2013

I have a LightSwitch 2013 RC project that fails with the error *"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information"* on launch. I don't know where to put a breakpoint, or a try..catch statement in order to have a look at the LoaderExceptions property. The project used the Silverlight desktop client, with forms authentication. I would appreciate some ideas on how to troubleshoot the problem and identify the offending/missing dll.